# How to solve $\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin\sqrt{x}}$ without the use of L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have tried manipulating the expression to get rid of the indeterminate form. I tried to use intervals and the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function for $x\rightarrow0^+$, we obtain:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}{\sin{\sqrt{x}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin{\sqrt{x}}}\right)=\sqrt{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin{\sqrt{x}}}=\sqrt1\cdot1=1.$$

Comment: should I feel bad for not figuring it out on my own? and how can I improve my ability?

Comment: @user500668 No! Just to solve, to solve and to solve and to learn from mistakes. Good luck!

Comment: thanks! how long do you think should I try solving myself before getting help?

Comment: @user500668 If you try to solve something without any success, try to read about something similar and to solve the problem, which you think that you understood, how to solve. I think if you'll do it, then you'll don't need the help from someone. By the way, it's not easy work, to write the full solution of the problem,which you think that you know to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(\sin x)/x\to1$ as $x\to0$, we have that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin\sqrt x}=\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{(\sin x)/x}}{\sqrt{x}(\sin\sqrt x)/\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{(\sin x)/x}}{(\sin\sqrt x)/\sqrt{x}}\to1
$$
as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

*hint*

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sin(\sqrt x)}=\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt x}{\sin(\sqrt{x})}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}x}\left(\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\right)^{-1}$$
isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

i would write
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to use the following Taylor expansions:

$$\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$$
$$\sin(\sqrt{x})=\sqrt{x}+O(\sqrt{x}^3).$$

You will obtain:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x+O(x^3)}}{\sqrt{x}+O(\sqrt{x}^3)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1+O(x^{2})}}{1+O(x)}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin\sqrt{x}}$$
First you must know the fundamental limits
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\sin t}=1$$
Then how to use it in this limit

I see a $\sqrt{\sin x}$ in the numerator so I need a $\sqrt{x}$ in the numerator. To compensate I multiply denominator by $\sqrt x$ and I get
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt x}\sqrt{\sin x}}{\color{red}{\sqrt x}\sin \sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sin \sqrt x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt {\sin x}}{\sqrt x}=1\cdot  \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{\frac{ {\sin x}}{x}}=1\cdot 1$$

Hope this is useful